# How do I locate Selenium Webdriver element for a html/Jquery snippet below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried using xpath but apparently I keep getting noelementfoundexception. I want to try and click on

#### Section 2

[image: HTML Snippet]

Comment: Would please provide details what element you trying to find and what Xpath you have tried so far?

Comment: You are trying to click on... what?

Comment: I should probably rephrase. Is it possible to click on <h3>Section 2</h3>? All h3s are expandable and collapsible accoridons.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you give the page enough time to load before you run your WebDriver API lookup, and you aren't executing any JavaScript that removes the H3 from the DOM, then this should work fine.

If you're having trouble with the XPath syntax there's no reason why you can't use `By.tagName('h3')` instead. However, I suspect that this is most likely a timing issue. It so often is.

Can you verify (by logging, by screenshot, by manual inspection + delays) that the H3 is definitely present before you check for it?